# Use the equivalence between representations and $kQ$-modules to find $\mathrm{rad}(P(i))$ and $\mathrm{top}(P(i))$

Tags: modules, representation-theory, radicals, quiver

**Question:** I had the exercise below (not graded) and I think I have all the components to solve it, but somehow I can't seem to find a proper proof. To what right $kQ$-modules do I have to relate $P(i)$ and $\mathrm{rad}(P(i))$ and how do I find the maximal ideals of the corresponding modules.

**What I know:**
The equivalence $\mathcal{G} \colon \mathrm{Rep}_Q \to \mathrm{Mod}_{kQ}$ gives
$\mathcal{G}(P(i)_j) = e_i kQ e_j$.

Define the *radical* of a module to be the intersection of all maximal submodules of $M$. Let $M$ be a right $A$-module. The quotient module
$$\mathrm{top}(M) = M/\mathrm{rad}(M)$$ is called the *top* of $M$.

**Exercise:**
Let $Q$ be a finite quiver without oriented cycles, and $P(i)$ the indecomposable right $kQ$-module associated to $i \in Q_0$.

**a)** We defined the radical of $P(i)$ as follows:
$$
  \mathrm{rad}(P(i))_j =
  \begin{cases}
    0      & \text{if $j = i$}, \\
    P(i)_j & \text{if $j \neq i$}.
  \end{cases}
$$
Show that this definition is indeed the intersection of all maximal submodules of $P(i)$ after identifying $\mathrm{rad}(P(i))$ and $P(i)$ with the corresponding right $kQ$-modules through the equivalence $\mathrm{Rep}_Q \simeq \mathrm{Mod}_{kQ}$.

**b)** Determine $\text{top}(P(i))$.